# How do i target the active state with css?

Tags: css, wordpress

[My SIte is Here](http://misha.pixelworklab.com/)

I need to make the active tab a different color than the rest.. Cant seem to get the navbar to play.. What am I misssing?

For example, if im on http://misha.pixelworklab.com/gallery/ I need the gallery tab to be a different color.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class for active list item is `.current-menu-item`, you need to target the `<a>` inside this active `li`,

So your css will be,

```
.current-menu-item > a
{
    background: green; /*your code here*/
}
```